# react-native rnpm windiows throws error

Tags: react-native

I am trying to build sample UWP app using react-native. Here is my package.JSON.

```
    `  {
  "name": "netizen_uwp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.2.0-rc.1",
    "react-native": "0.29.0-rc.0",
    "react-native-windows": "0.29.0-rc.0"
  },
  "main": "index.android.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "rnpm-plugin-windows": "^0.1.1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}`
```

When i run >rnpm windows,I am getting attached error even all my react/react-native/react-native-windows modules are latest.[image]

Can some one help me here?

Answer (score 0):

This is a general problem with react-native-windows being a plugin. We're always slightly behind the release train for react-native. You could have solved this problem using the --windowsVersion flag, as in:

rnpm windows --windowsVersion 0.29.0-rc.0

Also, as of react-native@>=0.31, you no longer need to use the rnpm global command line, and instance just use the command "react-native windows".